# How to create a US map in R with separation between states and clear labels?

Tags: r, cartography, labeling

I was trying to figure out how to create a map like down below in R on the Stack Exchange but maybe that's the wrong community and the GIS side is a better spot. Currently, I'm able to add the colours. I'm sort of able to get the labeling in place but some of the labels on the east coast are not readable.

I would like to be able to:

1. I would like to fix the labeling.
2. Split the states into groups

[image]

The Data:

```
PADDS<- structure(list(STATE = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), .Label = c("ALABAMA", "ALASKA", 
"ARIZONA", "ARKANSAS", "CALIFORNIA", "COLORADO", "CONNECTICUT", 
"DELAWARE", "FLORIDA", "GEORGIA", "HAWAII", "IDAHO", "ILLINOIS", 
"INDIANA", "IOWA", "KANSAS", "KENTUCKY", "LOUISIANA", "MAINE", 
"MARYLAND", "MASSACHUSETTS", "MICHIGAN", "MINNESOTA", "MISSISSIPPI", 
"MISSOURI", "MONTANA", "NEBRASKA", "NEVADA", "NEW HAMPSHIRE", 
"NEW JERSEY", "NEW MEXICO", "NEW YORK", "NORTH CAROLINA", "NORTH DAKOTA", 
"OHIO", "OKLAHOMA", "OREGON", "PENNSYLVANIA", "RHODE ISLAND", 
"SOUTH CAROLINA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "TENNESSEE", "TEXAS", "UTAH", 
"VERMONT", "VIRGINIA", "WASHINGTON", "WEST VIRGINIA", "WISCONSIN", 
"WYOMING"), class = "factor"), State = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), .Label = c("Alabama", 
"Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", 
"Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", 
"Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", 
"Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", 
"Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", 
"New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", 
"Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", 
"South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", 
"Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", 
"Wyoming"), class = "factor"), StateAbbreviation = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 24L, 26L, 29L, 
33L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 34L, 27L, 28L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 45L, 47L, 49L, 48L, 50L), .Label = c("AK", 
"AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "IA", 
"ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", "KY", "LA", "MA", "MD", "ME", "MI", "MN", 
"MO", "MS", "MT", "NC", "ND", "NE", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NV", "NY", 
"OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VA", 
"VT", "WA", "WI", "WV", "WY"), class = "factor"), PADD = structure(c(3L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("PADD I", "PADD II", "PADD III", "PADD IV", 
"PADD V"), class = "factor"), SubAreaInPADD = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Sub A", "Sub B", "Sub C"), class = "factor"), 
SubAreaInPADDName = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("", "Central Atlantic", "Lower Atlantic", "New England"
), class = "factor"), PADDName = structure(c(2L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("East Coast", "Gulf Coast", "MidWest", 
"Rocky Mountain", "West Coast"), class = "factor"), RMapClassName = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 32L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L), .Label = c("", "alabama", "arizona", "arkansas", "california", 
"colorado", "connecticut", "delaware", "florida", "georgia", 
"idaho", "illinois", "indiana", "iowa", "kansas", "kentucky", 
"louisiana", "maine", "maryland", "massachusetts:main", "michigan:north", 
"michigan:south", "minnesota", "mississippi", "missouri", 
"montana", "nebraska", "nevada", "new hampshire", "new jersey", 
"new mexico", "new york:long island", "new york:main", "north carolina:main", 
"north dakota", "ohio", "oklahoma", "oregon", "pennsylvania", 
"rhode island", "south carolina", "south dakota", "tennessee", 
"texas", "utah", "vermont", "virginia:main", "washington:main", 
"west virginia", "wisconsin", "wyoming"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("STATE", 
"State", "StateAbbreviation", "PADD", "SubAreaInPADD", "SubAreaInPADDName", 
"PADDName", "RMapClassName"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -52L))
```

code to create the map so far:

```
PADDS<-subset(PADDS, State != "Alaska")
PADDS<-subset(PADDS, State != "Hawaii")


PADD_Names<-unique(PADDS$PADDName)

map("state", interior = FALSE)
PADD1<-subset(PADDS, PADD=="PADD I")
PADD2<-subset(PADDS, PADD=="PADD II")
PADD3<-subset(PADDS, PADD=="PADD III")
PADD4<-subset(PADDS, PADD=="PADD IV")
PADD5<-subset(PADDS, PADD=="PADD V")

map('state', region = PADD1$RMapClassName, fill=TRUE, col="red", add=TRUE, names=TRUE)    # map of four states
map('state', region = PADD2$RMapClassName, fill=TRUE, col="green", add=TRUE, names=TRUE)    # map of four states
map('state', region = PADD3$RMapClassName, fill=TRUE, col="blue", add=TRUE, names=TRUE)    # map of four states
map('state', region = PADD4$RMapClassName, fill=TRUE, col="yellow", add=TRUE, names=TRUE)    # map of four states
map('state', region = PADD5$RMapClassName, fill=TRUE, col="purple", add=TRUE, names=TRUE)    # map of four states

map.text("state", regions=PADDS$RMapClassName, labels=as.character(PADDS$StateAbbreviation), add=TRUE) #add labels
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a suggestion using `ggplot`. It can be improved, but it gives you the basic idea.

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)

us.map <-  map_data('state')

# add PADD zones
us.map$PADD[us.map$region %in% 
          c("maine", "vermont", "new hampshire", "massachusetts", "connecticut", "rhode island",
            "new york", "pennsylvania", "new jersey", "delaware", "district of columbia", "maryland",
            "west virginia", "virginia", "north carolina", "south carolina", "georgia", "florida")] <- "PADD 1: East Coast"
us.map$PADD[us.map$region %in% 
          c("south dakota", "north dakota","nebraska", "kansas", "oklahoma", 
            "minnesota", "iowa", "missouri", "wisconsin", "illinois", "indiana",
            "michigan", "ohio", "kentucky", "tennessee")] <- "PADD 2: Midwest"
us.map$PADD[us.map$region %in% 
          c("new mexico", "texas", "arkansas", "louisiana", "alabama", "mississippi")] <- "PADD 3: Gulf Coast"
us.map$PADD[us.map$region %in% 
          c("montana", "idaho", "wyoming", "utah", "colorado")] <- "PADD 4: Rocky Mountain"
us.map$PADD[us.map$region %in% 
          c("washington", "oregon", "nevada", "arizona", "california")] <- "PADD 5: West Coast"

# subset the dataframe by padd zones and move lat/lon accordingly
us.map$lat.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 1: East Coast"] <- us.map$lat[us.map$PADD == "PADD 1: East Coast"]
us.map$long.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 1: East Coast"] <- us.map$long[us.map$PADD == "PADD 1: East Coast"] + 5

us.map$lat.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 2: Midwest"] <- us.map$lat[us.map$PADD == "PADD 2: Midwest"]
us.map$long.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 2: Midwest"] <- us.map$long[us.map$PADD == "PADD 2: Midwest"]

us.map$lat.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 3: Gulf Coast"] <- us.map$lat[us.map$PADD == "PADD 3: Gulf Coast"] - 3
us.map$long.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 3: Gulf Coast"] <- us.map$long[us.map$PADD == "PADD 3: Gulf Coast"]

us.map$lat.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 4: Rocky Mountain"] <- us.map$lat[us.map$PADD == "PADD 4: Rocky Mountain"]
us.map$long.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 4: Rocky Mountain"] <- us.map$long[us.map$PADD == "PADD 4: Rocky Mountain"] - 5

us.map$lat.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 5: West Coast"] <- us.map$lat[us.map$PADD == "PADD 5: West Coast"] - 2
us.map$long.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 5: West Coast"] <- us.map$long[us.map$PADD == "PADD 5: West Coast"] - 10

# add labels
states <- aggregate(cbind(long.transp, lat.transp) ~ region, data=us.map, 
                FUN=function(x)mean(range(x)))
states$labels <- c("AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FL", "GA", "IA", 
              "ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", "KY", "LA", "MA", "MD", "ME", "MI", "MN", 
              "MO", "MS", "MT", "NC", "ND", "NE", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NV", "NY", 
              "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VA", 
              "VT", "WA", "WI", "WV", "WY")

# plot and use padd zone as fill
ggplot(us.map,  aes(x=long.transp, y=lat.transp), colour="white") + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group, fill=PADD)) +
  geom_text(data=states, aes(long.transp, lat.transp, label=labels), size=3) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),  # remove background
    panel.grid = element_blank(), 
    axis.line = element_blank(), 
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank()) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]