# How to create a US map in R with separation between states, when using albersusa & plotly?

Tags: r, labeling, cartography, plotly, albers

**Does anyone have know how to access the longitude and latitude in albersusa?**

Currently, I'm working with a choropleth U.S. map in R using **albersusa** and the **plot_geo()** function from the **plotly** package (code provided further below).  However, I would like to shift some of the longitude and latitude points within albersusa to create small gaps between states and/or regions.

I have found exactly 1 post on Stack Exchange GIS ([How to create a US map in R with separation between states and clear labels?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141181/how-to-create-a-us-map-in-r-with-separation-between-states-and-clear-labels/141406#141406?newreg=ac5ed24c1fdb455ab78e02ae3c621bbe)) and 1 post on Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714456/how-to-map-cities-points-to-us-map-with-shifted-coordinates-to-allow-for-space-b) discussing this topic, **however**, both use a combination of the **maps** and **ggplot2** packages and result in output that I think are less than pretty, when compared to the following. [image]

```
state_ISO <- c("US-AL", "US-AK", "US-AZ", "US-AR", "US-CA", "US-CO", "US-CT", "US-DE", "US-FL", "US-GA", "US-HI", "US-ID", "US-IL", "US-IN", "US-IA", "US-KS", "US-KY", "US-LA", "US-ME", "US-MD", "US-MA", "US-MI", "US-MN", "US-MS", "US-MO", "US-MT", "US-NE", "US-NV", "US-NH", "US-NJ", "US-NM", "US-NY", "US-NC", "US-ND", "US-OH", "US-OK", "US-OR", "US-PA", "US-RI", "US-SC", "US-SD", "US-TN", "US-TX", "US-UT", "US-VT", "US-VA", "US-WA", "US-WV", "US-WI", "US-WY", "US-DC")
state_ISO2 <- c("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY", "DC")
sate_name <- c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming", "District of Columbia")
state_name_lower <- c("alabama", "alaska", "arizona", "arkansas", "california", "colorado", "connecticut", "delaware", "florida", "georgia", "hawaii", "idaho", "illinois", "indiana", "iowa", "kansas", "kentucky", "louisiana", "maine", "maryland", "massachusetts", "michigan", "minnesota", "mississippi", "missouri", "montana", "nebraska", "nevada", "new hampshire", "new jersey", "new mexico", "new york", "north carolina", "north dakota", "ohio", "oklahoma", "oregon", "pennsylvania", "rhode island", "south carolina", "south dakota", "tennessee", "texas", "utah", "vermont", "virginia", "washington", "west virginia", "wisconsin", "wyoming", "district of columbia")
type <- c("state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "state", "district")
regions_census_main <- c("South", "West", "West", "South", "West", "West", "Northeast", "South", "South", "South", "West", "West", "Midwest", "Midwest", "Midwest", "Midwest", "South", "South", "Northeast", "South", "Northeast", "Midwest", "Midwest", "South", "Midwest", "West", "Midwest", "West", "Northeast", "Northeast", "West", "Northeast", "South", "Midwest", "Midwest", "South", "West", "Northeast", "Northeast", "South", "Midwest", "South", "South", "West", "Northeast", "South", "West", "South", "Midwest", "West", "South")
regions_census_main_value <- c(3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3)

dataus <- as.data.frame(cbind(sate_ISO, sate_ISO2, state_name, state_name_lower, type,
regions_census_main, regions_census_main_value), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

g <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showlakes = TRUE,
  lakecolor = toRGB('white')
)

plot_geo(dataus, locationmode = 'USA-states') %>%
  add_trace(
    z = ~regions_census_main_value, locations = ~state_ISO2,
    color = ~regions_census_main_value, colors = 'Blues'
  ) %>%
  colorbar(title = "Regions") %>%
  layout(
    title = 'United States by Regions',
    geo = g
  )
```

It seems like the general concept to create the gaps between regions is to access the long and lat fields within the maps data and to perform a shift on those long and lat fields by region.  My initial observation is that this can be done with alberusa, since it is done for shifting Alaska and Hawaii using the points_elided() function.  The 1st answer to this Stack Exchange post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52911837/add-points-to-usmap-with-ggplot-in-r) eludes to the possibility of this, but as of October 2018 it seems like that functionality was not yet added.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Bulleted question lists are quick way to get your Question closed. Please [Edit] your Question to increase the focus.

Comment: @Vince, thank you for the guidance. I have reviewed the Tour and modified my post title and reduced my questions from 2 to 1.